# Random sample from huge CSV file

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have a huge CSV file which cannot be loaded into memory.

I want to randomly sample `N` elements from the file.

How do you recommend on doing that ?
Is there a Haskell library that does that ?
Is it possible to do it in constant memory ?

So far, I found the `sample` function in http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-extras-0.19/docs/Data-Random-Extras.html, but it needs to be loaded in a list.

Comment: "Is there a Haskell library that does that?" - such questions are explicitly off-topic on Stack Overflow. We're not a human search engine. As for "Is it possible to do it in constant memory?" - you could load fixed size chunks of the file and randomly decide if you want to pick any elements from the current chunk or not.

Comment: The `foldl` library provides a `randomN` streaming sink http://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl-1.4.6/docs/Control-Foldl.html#v:randomN that performs reservoir sampling https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling You can read the CSV line by line and feed the `FoldM` manually http://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl-1.4.6/docs/Control-Foldl.html#t:FoldM or you can use a streaming library like "conduit", "pipes" or "streaming", which have functions that connect streams to `FoldM` sinks. For example: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.3.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:foldM

Comment: Is there a reason that the standard reservoir sampling technique will not work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do you recommend on doing that ?

A streaming library to stream the data in constant memory and sampling function to select elements and give you your result.

> Is there a Haskell library that does that ?

Off topic, but see the comments.

> Is it possible to do it in constant memory ?

Yes, streaming and sampling is possible.  A more adhoc solution would be to select N random offsets in the file and parse the csv from there.   It wouldn't be uniform but probably would work for real world scenarios while also being faster than O(n).